# Dealing with recursion/sync-loops in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, aws-sdk

Right now I'm trying to build some code to handle lists over 100 items, as returned by the Amazon API endpoints. This requires building page-support into our data-gathering routines. This is my first time doing much with coffeescript, so I'm running into some conceptual walls here.

In a less async language, what I'm trying to do would be handleable using an `until` loop:

```
puts "Fetching launch configs"
next_token = ''
do
  if next_token.length > 0
    page_list = get_autoscale_configs(next_token)
  else
    page_list = get_autoscale_configs
  if page_list.NextToken is undefined
    next_token = ''
  else
    next_token = page_list.NextToken
until(next_token.length == 0)
```

The method of doing this in coffeescript is eluding me. What I have now...

```coffee
populate_configs = ( ) ->
  process_results = ( err data ) ->
    if err
      return err
    # do some logic
    if data.NextToken
      saved.next_token = data.NextToken
    else 
      saved.next_token = ''
    return console.log "Finished parsing #{data.LaunchConfigurations.length} items."
  if saved.next_token = ''
    autoscaling.describeLaunchConfigurations {
      MaxRecords: 100, StartToken: next_token
    }, ( err, data ) -> process_results( err, data )
  else
    autoscaling.describeLaunchConfigurations {
      MaxRecords: 100
    }, ( err, data ) -> process_results( err, data )
```

And then in the body of the code, this function is invoked:

```coffee
saved = {}
async.series [ 
  ( series_cb ) ->
    saved.next_token = ''
     async.doWhilst populate_configs,
       saved.next_token.length > 4,
       ( err ) ->
         if err
           # complain about it.
         # else, log success
         return series_cb()
  # more callbacks
]
```

The idea here being that `populate_configs` is called by [doWhilst](https://github.com/caolan/async#doWhilst), which then fetches a list of launch_configs out of amazon. The data is then passed into another function called `process_results`, which persists things that should be persisted and sets variables for `next_token`. It returns, and doWhilst tests to see if the test is passing (the string-length of `saved.next_token` is long enough to be data); if it passes, it runs through `populate_configs` again, if it fails, it runs the third callback.

What I'm getting right now is that the first iteration of that `populate_configs` block is executed, but then the entire execution stops dead at that point. None of the calls in the error-handler of [doWhilst](https://github.com/caolan/async#doWhilst) are being executed.

Clearly, I'm misunderstanding how callbacks work and how to get myself out of this hole. This part needs to be synchronous. Once I have this list built, I can do all sorts of async fun with the list I'm building. But I need the list first.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is here: `if saved.next_token = ''`. You set `next_token` to `''` so `populate_configs` runs only once. The comparaison is done with `==` or `is` in CoffeeScript.

Also, `( err, data ) -> process_results( err, data )` can be replaced by `process_results`.